# Why is $n = \frac{n}{1}$?

Tags: arithmetic, fractions

Why is n (a number) = $\frac{n}{1}$?

My reasoning is as follows:

For a fraction $\frac{a}{b}$, b (denominator) is the number of *equal parts* the whole (1) is divided into and a (numerator) *counts* how many of these parts we're interested in. So  e.g. $\frac{2}{5}$, read as *two-fifths*, represents 1 broken up into 5 equal parts and taking 2 of them.

Quite naturally then n = $\frac{n}{1}$ as $1$ is "divided" into 1 equal "parts" which is again 1 and we take n of them   (n $\times$ 1 = n).

Ergo, my brain tells me n = $\frac{n}{1}$

Is my argument sound? Is there a better (simpler/shorter/correct) proof?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Your way of thinking is basically correct. In more "mathematical" terms, if $b \not = 0$, the fraction $\frac{a}{b}$ is the unique number characterized by the property that if you multiply it by $b$, you recover $a$. In other words, $\frac{a}{b}$ is the unique solution of the equation $bx = a$ with unknown $x$. In particular, $\frac{n}{1}$ is the only solution of the equation $1\times x = n$. Since $n$ is clearly also a solution of this equation, by unicity we have $\frac{n}{1} = n$.

Comment: I'm not really sure why this got multiple downvotes. It's an elementary question, but there's nothing wrong with elementary questions.

Comment: Wow! Amazing response @Suzet. Gracias for it. 1 × n = n and 1 × n/1 = n and so n = n/1.

Comment: @Noah Schweber, no explanations for the downvotes.

Comment: The number $1$ is the identity element so $1\cdot a=a$ for all $a$. An inverse for a number $a$ is a number called $a^{-1}$ with the property that $aa^{-1}=a^{-1}a=1$. We also write $a^{-1}$ as $\frac{1}{a}$. Now, $1$ is its own inverse so $1=\frac{1}{1}$ and $1\cdot n=n$. Therefore $n=\frac{1}{1}\cdot n=\frac{n}{1}$.

Comment: @Suzet, here's another way to think about it. $\frac{a}{b} \times \frac{1}{1} = \frac{a \times 1}{b \times 1} = \frac{a}{b}$. But $\frac{a}{b} \times 1 = \frac{a}{b}$. Thus, $\frac{1}{1} = 1$ . Now $\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{1} = \frac{1 + 1}{1} = \frac{2}{1} = 1 + 1 = 2$. Adding $\frac{1}{1}$ n times yields $\frac{n}{1}$ = n × 1 = n. In essence, $\frac{n}{1} = n$

Comment: @JohnDouma, gracias. Can you take a look at my proof, the comment preceding this one?

Comment: @AgentSmith De nada. Your proof seems overly complicated. We can get to $1=\frac{1}{1}$ more directly. If we are allowed to say that the sum of $n$ copies of $\frac{1}{1}=\frac{n}{1}$ then why not just use multiplication directly? The bottom line in a proof like this is to consider the set of axioms we are given to start with. For example, are we allowed to assume that if $ac=bc$ then $a=b$? That seems to be how you proved that $1=\frac{1}{1}$.

Comment: @JohnDouma, thanks for the feedback. I'm trying to avoid *circularity* in my proof. Does any step in my proof that $\frac{n}{1} = n$ involve $\frac{n}{1} = n$? The step where I go from ac = bc to a = b requires its own proof of course but I can assume it as an axiom or proven theorem for the moment, right? Also, my objective is to prove that a ÷ b = $\frac{a}{b}$ via $\frac{a}{1} \div \frac{b}{1}$

Comment: Suzet's proof is just much better than either your argument in the post, or re-interpretation in the comments. It comes directly from the definition of division and the definition of $1$. $1$ is the multiplicative identity: $1\times x = x$ for any $x$. And $\frac ab$ is defined as the number such that $b\times \frac ab = a$. All your concepts are much further removed from these definitions, require additional facts to be proven, and are more complicated.

Comment: Ok @PaulSinclair. **Suzet**'s proof is as follows: $\frac{n}{1} \times 1 = n$ AND n × 1 = n. Ergo $\frac{n}{1}$ = n.

Comment: Yes. That is what I am referring to. The first is the definition of division: $\frac n1$ is the number which when multiplied by $1$ gives $n$, and the second is the definition of the multiplicative identity $1$: multiplying $n$ by $1$ gives $n$.

Comment: Division is reverse multiplication (8 $\div$ 2 is saying "what number times 2 is 8?")  1$n = n$ is an axiom.

Comment: Today's edit makes the argument in the question wrong. $n$ divided into 1 part is $n$, not 1.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we have enough contributions now that confirm OP's thinking.

Comment: @KurtG, ok, but **Noah Schweber** got **15** likes/upvotes. Of course I'll say that?

Comment: Is that a reason to start an open ended discussion?

Comment: Money ain't my strong suit, but, *15* upvotes (local max) is an indicator of (high) *demand*?

Comment: Or a sign of boredom and inability to think about more interesting questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler and more straightforward proof flows from the multiplicative identity axiom and the definition of *divides*.

For any real numbers $a$ and $b$, we say $a$ divides $b$ and write $\frac{b}{a} = k$ if and only if there exists a real number $k$ such that $ak = b$. In other words, you may interpret the statement $\frac{b}{a} = k$ as saying exactly $k$ multiplies of $a$ equal $b$.

According to the multiplicative identity law, we have $n \cdot 1 = n$ for every real number $n$. So, by definition of divides, $1$ divides $n$ and we may write

$$ \frac{n}{1} = n $$

meaning exactly $n$ multiples of $1$ equal $n$. The multiplicative identity law also implies $n$ divides $n$ and we may write

$$ \frac{n}{n} = 1 $$

meaning exactly $1$ multiple of $n$ equals $n$.

Comment: Arigato, but the assumption here is that $\frac{n}{1} = n \div 1$. That isn't "permitted" in the system I'm in right now. You see if $a \div b = \frac{a}{1} \div \frac{b}{1}$ then (note here that $a = \frac{a}{1}$ has to be an independent theorem), then I can do this: $\frac{a}{1} \times \frac{1}{b} = \frac{a}{b}$, *proving* $a \div b = \frac{a}{b}$. I want to avoid a *circulos in probando*.

Comment: @AgentSmith What system are you in? It doesn't seem to be mentioned in the question. If you want a non-circular proof then you need to give more precise definitions of the notations and terms you are using; also a decent listing of the facts that may be used in the proof.

Comment: Apologies for the delay. The mathematical equivalent of *baby logic* i.e. *baby math*. @DavidK. A very soulcrushing name for those who have to struggle.

Comment: @AgentSmith Could you provide a link to where this system of *baby logic* is described? I haven't heard of it before, and I couldn't find it after performing an internet search. The derivation of $\frac{n}{1} = n$ above proceeds directly from the definition of *divides* and an axiom of the real numbers known as the *multiplicative identity law*, so there is no circularity here. In other words, I am not assuming the very thing I'm trying to prove. You can go on to prove something like $\frac{b}{a} = \frac{b}{1} \cdot \frac{1}{a}$, and it all rests on the definition and axiom I just mentioned.

Comment: We may not use $\frac{a}{b} = k$ because it *assumes* $a \div b = \frac{a}{b}$ (this is what I want to prove). By the way, *spasibo*.

Comment: I believe most mathematicians regard $\frac{a}{b}$ and $a \div b$ as meaning the same exact thing. They are two different symbols for the same idea, so both expressions are interchangeable. And $\frac{a}{b} = k \Leftrightarrow bk = a$ is true by definition of divides.

Answer (score 1):

To answer such question you need to define what $\frac{a}{b}$ symbol means. Math is a science of precision.

So in a typical setup you would have a pair $(R,\cdot)$, where $R$ is a set and $\cdot$ is a function $R\times R\to R$ typically called "multiplication". Of course "set" is a primitive object, while function and Cartesian product have their own definitions as well.

Additionally we would have a special element $1\in R$ such that $x\cdot 1=1\cdot x=x$ for any $x\in R$. Then you can prove that such $1$ is unique if it exists. This element is often called neutral or multiplicative identity.

Finally the symbol $\frac{a}{b}$ for $a,b\in R$ is defined as $a\cdot b^{-1}$, where $b^{-1}$ is defined as an element of $R$ such that $b\cdot b^{-1}=b^{-1}\cdot b=1$, i.e. the inverse of $b$. This is under assumption that $\cdot$ is commutative (not a strict requirement but without it $\frac{a}{b}$ behaves in a weird, counterintuitive way, e.g. $\frac{a}{b}\cdot\frac{c}{d}$ is not necessarily equal to $\frac{a\cdot c}{b\cdot d}$). Again if $b$ has an inverse then it has to be unique.

Note that the symbol "$-1$" here is not related to the special neutral element $1\in R$. These are two different things that share the same symbol. Also "$x^{-1}$" does not refer to exponentiation, it literally stands for "the inverse of $x$". Both might be confusing but it is a standard mathematical convention to use such symbols. Those two are connected with the standard meaning, but that's a story for another time.

With all of that we easily see that $1\cdot 1=1$ and therefore $1^{-1}=1$. And so for any $n\in R$ we have

$$\frac{n}{1}=n\cdot 1^{-1}=n\cdot 1=n$$

Comment: Nice! Circularity-meter is giving a reading. Perhaps mine is broken. Not a problem though, it's easy to lose your bearings in what is a jungle of ideas.

Comment: @AgentSmith I assure you there is no circularity involved here. Feel free to ask questions if anything is unclear.

Comment: It's a roundabout way of using $a \times \frac{1}{a} = 1$. A necessary requirement would be an alternative and yet valid route (consistent with how *fractions* behave). About the circularity ... you're using *exponents*, and that *comes after* *fractions*. Top-down, ok, but bottom-up better, oui?

Comment: @AgentSmith I am not using exponents. You misinterpreted what "$x^{-1}$" actually is, even though I precisely defined it in the answer. This has nothing to do with exponentiation. Perhaps I wasn't clear enough, I've updated the answer.

Comment: I see. So we have the *identity element* for multiplication, $1$ and what you're employing here is the *multiplicative inverse*, for a number $n$, it would be $n^{-1}$ such that $n \times n^{-1} = 1$. That would mean $n \div 1 = n \times 1^{-1} = n \times 1 = 1$. What about $\frac{n}{1}$? Before I use your definition, I have to be shown $\frac{n}{1} = n \div 1$.

Comment: @AgentSmith for me (and many mathematicians) $\frac{a}{b}$ and $a \% b$ is literally the same thing, synonyms. So there's nothing to show here. As I said in my answer the symbol $\frac{a}{b}$ is typically **defined** as $a\cdot b^{-1}$. This is a good definition if we know how to multiply (given) and how to take inverse (as defined earlier). And this actually avoids circular reference, as in defining $\frac{a}{b}$ as $a\% b$.